# purrr: How to intersect one list with several nested lists

Tags: r, purrr

I have a data.frame containing parties in government. These parties are nested in a list column grouped by period (= each year).

I want to compare the overlap between each government and previous governments.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~period, ~party, ~seats,
        1,    "A",      2,
        1,    "B",      3,
        1,    "C",      3,
        2,    "A",      2,
        2,    "C",      3,
        3,    "C",      4,
        3,    "E",      1,
        3,    "F",      3
  )


df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(period) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(gov=map(data, "party") %>% map(.,list)) %>% 
  mutate(prev.govs=map(data, "party") %>% 
           map(., list) %>%
           accumulate(.,union))
```

To make the comparison I created a list which includes nested lists for each previous government (`prev.govs`). Each nested list shoudl be compared (`intersect`) with the list containing the present government (`gov`). Here's where I got stuck.

I tried to use `map2` of the `purrr` package and compare the list containing the parties of the present gov with the (nested) lists containing parties of previous governments (prev.govs). Unfortunately, here I get stuck.

Failed approaches:

```
df2 <- df1%>% 
  mutate(rep=map2(.x=gov, .y=prev.govs, .f=intersect))

df2 <- df1%>% 
  mutate(rep=map(gov, ~map2(., prev.govs, intersect)))

df2 <- df1%>% 
  mutate(rep=modify_depth(prev.govs, 2, ~map2(.,gov, intersect)))
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
#> * `.x` has length 2
#> * `.y` has length 3.
```

What I am trying to get is for each period a list with nested lists for each previous government. Each nested list contains the parties which overlap with the present government. A simplified case on two list hopefully makes this sufficiently clear:

```
new <- list(c("A" ,"C", "E", "F"))
old <- list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("A", "C"), c("D", "E", "F"))

map2(new, old, intersect)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A" "C"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "A" "C"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "E" "F"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below syntax is more clear and also more convenient for debugging because you can throw a breakpoint inside the first map2 code block and check the shape of the data.

```
df1$comparison <- map2(df1$gov, df1$prev.govs, function(curGov, prevGov) {
  map2(curGov, prevGov, intersect)
})
```

but if you want to stick to `mutate`, you can do the following. However, I think it's very confusing and it's better maybe just use the full named function.

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(comparison = map2(gov, prev.govs, ~map2(.x, .y, intersect)))

# or better use named parameters

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(
    comparison = map2(
      gov, 
      prev.govs,
      function(curGov, prevGov) {
        map2(curGov, prevGov, intersect)
      }
    )
  )
```

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks. Nesting map2 functions was new to me.

Comment: if you don't mind, i would have a follow-up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752196/purrr-joining-tibbles-nested-in-different-list-columns