# purrr: joining tibbles nested in different list columns

Tags: r, purrr

This is essentially a follow-up question to a previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582821/purrr-how-to-intersect-one-list-with-several-nested-lists/54583346?noredirect=1#comment95988216_54583346) which `@keqiang-li` kindly answered.

I have a dataframe which includes a list column (nested data-frames) comprising parties to a government and the number of their respective seats. This dataframe is split per country (note I used the new `dplyr` 0.8 `group_nest` and `group_split`).

What I am essentially trying is to get another list column which features for each goverment a list for each previous government which holds a dataframe indicating the overlap of parties and seats.

```
library(tidyverse)


df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~period, ~party, ~seats,
  1,    "A",      2,
  1,    "B",      3,
  1,    "C",      3,
  2,    "A",      2,
  2,    "C",      3,
  3,    "C",      4,
  3,    "E",      1,
  3,    "F",      3
)

df <- bind_rows(AA=df, BB=df, .id="country")

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(country, period) %>% 
  group_nest() %>% 
  #mutate(gov=map(data, "party") %>% map(.,list)) %>% 
  mutate(prev.govs=map(data, "party") %>% 
           map(., list) %>%
           accumulate(.,union))

df <- df %>% 
  group_split(country) %>% 
  map(., ~mutate(., prev.govs.df=map_depth(prev.govs, 2, enframe, value="party")))
```

df is my point of departure. Below unsucessful attempts.

```
##attempts
df %>% 
  map(., ~mutate(., df.overlap=map_depth(prev.govs.df, 3, ~map2(., data, inner_join))))
#> Error in UseMethod("inner_join"): nicht anwendbare Methode für 'inner_join' auf Objekt der Klasse "c('integer', 'numeric')" angewendet

df %>% 
  map(., ~mutate(., df.overlap=map_depth(prev.govs.df, 2, ~map2(., data, inner_join))))
#> Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
#> * `.x` has length 2
#> * `.y` has length 3

df %>% 
  map(., ~mutate(., df.overlap=map2(data, prev.govs.df, ~map2(.x, .y, ~map2(.x, .y, inner_join)))))
#> Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
#> * `.x` has length 3
#> * `.y` has length 2
```

On a more specific level, the solution for `country` AA in period 3 would be the 3 lists each with a tibble containing the rows from `data` which overlapped with those in `prev.govs.def` on the `party` column (key)

```
df[[1]][["prev.govs.df"]][[3]] 
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    name party
#>   <int> <chr>
#> 1     1 A    
#> 2     2 B    
#> 3     3 C    
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>    name party
#>   <int> <chr>
#> 1     1 A    
#> 2     2 C    
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    name party
#>   <int> <chr>
#> 1     1 C    
#> 2     2 E    
#> 3     3 F
df[[1]][["data"]][[3]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   party seats
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 C         4
#> 2 E         1
#> 3 F         3
```

The answer to the previouus question solved the riddle how to intersect two lists. Unfortuantley, I couldn't figure out how to make the next step entailing splitting the dataframe and merging nested tibbles.

Greatful for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's third attempt is actually really close. We just need to modify the last `map` like the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

output <- df %>%
  map(~mutate(., df.overlap = map2(data, prev.govs.df, ~map(.y, inner_join, .x))))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  country period data             prev.govs  prev.govs.df df.overlap
  <chr>    <dbl> <list>           <list>     <list>       <list>    
1 AA           1 <tibble [3 x 2]> <list [1]> <list [1]>   <list [1]>
2 AA           2 <tibble [2 x 2]> <list [2]> <list [2]>   <list [2]>
3 AA           3 <tibble [3 x 2]> <list [3]> <list [3]>   <list [3]>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  country period data             prev.govs  prev.govs.df df.overlap
  <chr>    <dbl> <list>           <list>     <list>       <list>    
1 BB           1 <tibble [3 x 2]> <list [3]> <list [3]>   <list [3]>
2 BB           2 <tibble [2 x 2]> <list [3]> <list [3]>   <list [3]>
3 BB           3 <tibble [3 x 2]> <list [3]> <list [3]>   <list [3]>

> output[[1]]$df.overlap[[3]]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
   name party seats
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1     3 C         4

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
   name party seats
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1     2 C         4

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   name party seats
  <int> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 C         4
2     2 E         1
3     3 F         3
```

Comment: Many thanks. Could you briefly explain the magic behind ~map(.y, inner_join, .x). How come that inner_join comes before .x? I didn't gather that from the documentation.

Comment: With that `map`, we&#39;re applying the `inner_join` function over each element of `.y` with `.x` as an additional argument. In `?map`, you will see the `...` refers to any additional arguments to be fed to the function `.f`. So this code is equivalent to `inner_join(.y[[1]], .x)` for the first iteration for example, or `map(.y, function(y) inner_join(y, .x))` in general.

Answer (score 2):

One reason would be the issue with the difference in `length` of `list` elements.  We could `rep`licate one of the `list` elements to make the lengths same and then do the `inner_join`

```
out <- df %>%
         map(., ~ .x %>% 
             mutate(df.overlap = map2(prev.govs.df, data, ~ 
                map2(rep(list(.y), length(.x)), .x, inner_join))))
```

-output

```
out[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  country period data             prev.govs  prev.govs.df df.overlap
#  <chr>    <dbl> <list>           <list>     <list>       <list>    
#1 AA           1 <tibble [3 × 2]> <list [1]> <list [1]>   <list [1]>
#2 AA           2 <tibble [2 × 2]> <list [2]> <list [2]>   <list [2]>
#3 AA           3 <tibble [3 × 2]> <list [3]> <list [3]>   <list [3]>

# overlap column element
out[[1]]$df.overlap[[3]][[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  party seats  name
#  <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1 C         4     3


# input dataset elements used for joining
out[[1]]$data[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  party seats
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 C         4
#2 E         1
#3 F         3

out[[1]]$prev.govs.df[[3]][[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   name party
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 A    
#2     2 B    
#3     3 C
```